# Tomcat request incorrectly changed to include ".jsp" within Grails application

Tags: tomcat, model-view-controller, grails, grails-4

We are moving a Grails 4 application from Oracle to Postgres, and from one server to another.  We can run our application without issues locally (using `run-app`), so we don't think the Oracle -> Postgres transition is responsible for the issue we are seeing; we believe it's because of the switch from one environment to another.

We are seeing an issue where a request to "/OurApp/loginStatus/" that we would like to be handled by the Grails **defaultAction**.  We would really like this URL to be mapped to "OurApp/loginStatus/index" which it does in other environments.

Here is a pared-down LoginStatusController:

```
class LoginStatusController {

    def index() {
        render([success: true] as JSON)
    }
}
```

**Tomcat Logging**

We turned on the `RequestDumperFilter` and this is where you see a difference between the URL and application path:

> requestURI=/OurApp/loginStatus/

> servletPath=/loginStatus/index.jsp

**Application Logging**

Adding additional spring-security logging gives us this:

> Request received for '/loginStatus/index.jsp':

> servletPath:/loginStatus/index.jsp

**Configuration**

I've gone over the `server.xml`, `web.xml`, and `context.xml` and I don't see anything that would explain why our new environment treats these requests differently.

We can't tell if Tomcat or Grails is *at fault* for the problem, or even how to debug further.  The new server is only accessibly through a remote Windows OS that is lacking in tools to do any sort of remote debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem was a catalina option added to the `tomcat.service` file.  The particular option was:
`org.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE=true`

This was added along with several other options (`RECYCLE_FACADES`, `ALLOW_BACKSPLASH`, etc.) as a means to secure the server in the new environment without consideration of the impact.

Here is the official Tomcat 8 configuration documentation about this setting:

> The default value of this system property is false.
>
> If this is true the default values will be changed for:
>
> - org.apache.catalina.core.
>   ApplicationContext.GET_RESOURCE_REQUIRE_SLASH
> - org.apache.catalina.core. ApplicationDispatcher.WRAP_SAME_OBJECT
> - org.apache.catalina.core. StandardHostValve.ACCESS_SESSION
> - org.apache.catalina.session. StandardSession.ACTIVITY_CHECK
> - org.apache.catalina.session. StandardSession.LAST_ACCESS_AT_START
> - org.apache.tomcat.util.http. ServerCookie.STRICT_NAMING
> - The URIEncoding attribute of any HTTP connector or AJP connector element.
> - The resourceOnlyServlets attribute of any Context element. The tldValidation attribute of any Context element.
> - The useRelativeRedirects attribute of any Context element.
> - The xmlNamespaceAware attribute of any Context element.
> - The xmlValidation attribute of any Context element.

We reverted that option only and our servlet paths were no longer changed between Tomcat and the application.